# loading the appended data by ajax

Tags: html, ajax

Hello all i want to ask how to reload the appended data ..
Actually i am having a page which goes infinite scrolling ..
and i need to reload the appending elements when clicked on a particular element ..
the loading is fine for the elements that are not appending (previously present when the page loads) .

loading by ajax is working fine (checked)
just wana ask how to use load method of ajax for the divs in the appended data..

```
$("#abc").load("load.php #abc");
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a problem with your events. If you are using the `.click` or `.bind` event handler of jQuery, the new added elements will not be targeted. Try `$(".clickable").live("click", function());` to make also the newly added elements clickable.

As jQuery documentation says:
http://api.jquery.com/live/

> Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.